# The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/octet-stream" Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, three.js

this is my project strucure:

- node_modules.
- server.js
- public:

  - glsl:

    - fragment.glsl
    - vertex.glsl
  - index.html
  - main.js
  - img.jpg
  - style.css

I have got a simple server setup to serve a three.js animation
server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path')
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public')
const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, ()=>{

  console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
      <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>heloo</h1> 
<canvas id="app"></canvas> 
   
</body>
```

main.js

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/build/three.module.js';

import { OrbitControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import vertexShader from "./glsl/vertex.glsl";
import fragmentShader from "./glsl/fragment.glsl";
import img from "./mannequin.jpg";

class Gl {
    
  constructor() {

    
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      45,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      100
    );

    this.camera.position.z = 1;
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: document.querySelector("#app"),
      antialias: true
    });
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);

    this.clock = new THREE.Clock();

    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);

    this.onResize();
  }

  init() {
    this.createMesh();
    this.addEvents();
  }

  createMesh() {
    this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0.4, 0.6, 32, 32);
    this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      vertexShader,
      fragmentShader,
      uniforms: {
        uTime: { value: 0.0 },
        uTexture: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(img) }
      },
      // wireframe: true,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
    this.scene.add(this.mesh);
  }

  addEvents() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.run.bind(this));
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onResize.bind(this), false);
  }

  run() {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.run.bind(this));
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    this.material.uniforms.uTime.value = this.clock.getElapsedTime();
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

  onResize() {
    const w = window.innerWidth;
    const h = window.innerHeight;

    this.camera.aspect = w / h;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    this.renderer.setSize(w, h);
  }
}

export default Gl;

 
const scene = new Gl();
scene.init();
```

when I start the server and go to the localhost port I get these errors:

vertex.glsl:1 failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

fragment.glsl:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

mannequin.jpg:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "image/jpeg". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Answer (score 0):

a workaround for glsl for me is:

```
const grassShader = {}

async function getShaders() {
  grassShader.vert = (await fetch('./grass.vert.glsl').then(x => x.text()));
  grassShader.frag = (await fetch('./grass.frag.glsl').then(x => x.text()));
}

await getShaders()
```

Answer (score -1):

Browsers only support JavaScript modules with `import`.

If you want to import other things (like images or glsl files) then you'll need to use Webpack with suitable loader modules (like webpack-glsl-loader) and build the application before loading it into the browser.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
I kind of wanted to avoid using any bundlers. is there any other way?